# How is a dynamic array different from statically bound array in C++?

Tags: c++

I am learning C++ and I just read about dynamic arrays and how it lets you set the length of an array during runtime rather than during compile time. However, you don't need a dynamic array to do this. So what is the point of a dynamic array; when would you use it? I feel like I am missing something obvious so any insight is much appreciated. Thanks!

```
// Static binding.
int size = 0;

cout << "Enter size of array:" << endl;
cin >> size;

int array[size];

int array_length = sizeof(array) / sizeof(int);
cout << "Number of elements in array: " << array_length << endl;

// I just set the length of an array dynamically without using a dynamic array.
// So whats the point of a dynamic array then?
```

Comment: I think the compiler that you are using lets you assign a variable as a size of an array as an extra feature. It still uses dynamic arrays in the backend to accomplish that, as you are technically not allowed to assign variable sizes to arrays.

Comment: sizeof(array) is calculated in compile-time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do that in C++. Only C99 allows variable-length arrays.

Does this even compile? Were you talking about the `vector` class?

EDIT:

It does not compile in Visual Studio 2010:

```
1>..\main.c(207): error C2057: expected constant expression
1>..\main.c(207): error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
1>..\main.c(207): error C2133: 'array' : unknown size
1>..\main.c(209): error C2070: 'int []': illegal sizeof operand
```

Comment: It works just like you think it would. I am running whatever compiler comes with Xcode 4 on the mac and no I am talking about `int *array = new int[dynamic_size];` type of dynamic arrays.

Comment: Then it's definitely a compiler extension. I'm close to 100% positive that this isn't specified in any C++ standard to date.

Comment: Okay so the code I wrote above probably wouldn't work with another compiler; I would actually have to use a legitimate dynamic array instead?

Comment: Correct, you'll have to dynamically allocate an array with `new`. (and `delete` it later)

Comment: Okay thanks. I understand you would have to use a dynamic array with any other compiler; my compiler just misled me because it supports variable length array sizes.

Answer (score 1):

You would need a dynamically allocated array for cases where you don't know ahead of time how many items you will have.

Another (and better) option is to use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1):

As per the standard, an array defined "statically" would:

1. have a constant size, defined *at compile time*
2. Be allocated *on the stack* rather than the heap.

So the reasons you'd opt for a dynamically allocated array (using `new type[]`) are because you don't always know the size you need for an array at compile time, and the stack is a limited resource that you often need to be careful not to exhaust.

But in practical terms, you'd often be best served by using std::vector or other STL container instead of a builtin array of any sort.

Answer (score 1):

Your example would not compile under a standards-compliant compiler. For instance, GCC says this:

http://codepad.org/Kvq2PfNx

> In function 'int main()':
>   Line 13: error: ISO C++ forbids variable-size array 'array'
>   compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.

There is a way of dynamically allocating stack memory using the [alloca](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/gnulib/alloca.html) function. However, this memory is invalidated when the function terminates. You should generally prefer `new[]/delete[]` or `std::vector` for dynamic memory allocation.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically create an array using the keyword new..
Lets say you don't know ahead of time how many values you need. It's a waste of space to declare an array a[100] when the user might just enter a few values. Also the user might enter more values, and then you would have a array overflow error.
You can create an array dynamically like -  int a = new int[] 
Also, statically created arrays are created on the stack where as dynamically created arrays are created on the heap-which means the memory is globally available even after the function goes out of scope.